# Current Reading Position and Progress in iBooks with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, ibooks

I'm trying to calculate the current reading position and reading progress of an ePub opened in iBooks. In other reading systems (like Readium or even Adobe RMSDK) to get the position of the content relative to the viewport we can use

```
var firstRect = nodes[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var lastRect = nodes[nodes.length- 1].getBoundingClientRect();
```

So we can calculate the progress like

```
var progress=firstRect.left+lastRect.left>0?Math.round(Math.abs(firstRect.left*100)/(Math.abs(firstRect.left)+lastRect.left)):100;
```

Although iBooks is Webkit based and allows the use of js somewhat compliant to the ePub3 standard - the position of the rects does NOT change when the content is scrolled in the iBooks view, i.e. it always stays the same.

I'm stuck here. Any thoughts?

I want to integrate this functionality into my open source library [epubTrack.js](https://github.com/epubtrack/epubtrack-js)

Comment: If you can use javascript can you not use $(window).scroll(function () and then hit the window.pageYOffset?

Comment: Thanks gerdi, unfortunately neither the scroll event is fired nor does the window.pageYOffset have any other value than 0 regardless of scrolling through the pages.